# Singleton Pattern for DbContext Entity Framework in Asp.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, design-patterns, singleton

```
public class SingletonContext<TContext> where TContext : DbContext, new()
{
    private static TContext _db;
    private static object _lockSync = new object();
    public SingletonContext()
    {

    }


    public static TContext CreateContext()
    {
        if (_db == null)
        {
            lock (_lockSync)
            {
                _db = new TContext();
            }

        }
        return _db;

    }
}
```

I apply singleton pattern for dbcontext in my project like that because when i want update operation my entity throws multiple references exception.I chanced my code and problem  is solved.Anyway actually
the question is different.
I trying update to my entity but i didnt because modelstate is not valid.No problem so for.

[this property that i updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kwr9C.png)

I dont understand that when i will select my entity from db returned to me like that

[after try update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2npoy.png)

But my entity not seted null ,as you can see.

[view of my entity in db after update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4r9Fp.png)

The method below select operation in Data Accsess layer

```
 public TEntity Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter)
    {
        TContext context = SingletonContext<TContext>.CreateContext(); //i called my static method that create singleton dbcontext
            return context.Set<TEntity>().SingleOrDefault(filter);
    }
```

what i want to learn is  does it singleton pattern  work like that?
I expects my entity return to me with value. Not null.
Is there something wrong i did something? or  Singleton pattern work in Entity Framework like that?

Comment: I highly recommend against using `DbContext` as singleton.

Comment: I agree.but as i said not returning with actual value my entity.